# Why is my if statement running even though the requirements aren't true?

Tags: php, session

I am making a button that I only want admins to view. Each user has a rank in the database and if rank is set to "a" they have admin access. This works on other pages, such as viewing the "Admin Panel" page and such but here it doesn't for some reason. Even when you are not logged in you can view the special button.

```
$viewer = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $sql33="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$viewer'";
    $result33 = $mysqli->query($sql33);
    $rows33=$result33->fetch_assoc();
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']['username']) AND $_SESSION['user']['rank'] == "a" or "p") {
    ?><a href="deletepost.php?id=<? echo $id ?>"><input type="submit" value="DELETE"></a><?
    }
```

The button displays no matter what, and when I'm not logged in this error occurs:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in /home/parap00per/public_html/view_topic.php on line 62
```

Line 62 is the bit where I define $viewer.

I presume it's because there is no session if you're not logged in, but even when I'm logged into an account that doesn't have admin acces (neither "a" nor "p") this if statement still runs and the button still appears. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I have used $_SESSION['user'] stuff on other pages before, and all I need to use them is to include a file called common.php, which is included on this page.

So my question in brief: Why is this if statement running even if it's not true?

Comment: This doesn't do what you intend it to: `AND $_SESSION['rank'] == "a" or "p"`

Comment: I changed it to $_SESSION['user']['rank'] like it's supposed to be but it still didn't do anything. What should I change this to then?

Comment: You'll need a `()` group on these, and complete boolean comparisons:  `&& ($_SESSION['rank'] == 'a' || $_SESSION['rank'] == 'p')`

Comment: A note about PHP style - although the keyword operators `and, or` will work correctly here, they are not quite the same as the logical operators `&&, ||` [due to their precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). The latter are more commonly used in this context than the `and,or` keywords.

Comment: I realize this, I think I just switched them to the words at some point due to my frustration. I will change them back now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly compare `$_SESSION['user']['rank']` with both `"p"` and `"a"`:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['username']) && 
        ($_SESSION['user']['rank'] == "a" || $_SESSION['user']['rank'] == "p") {
    ?><a href="deletepost.php?id=<? echo $id ?>"><input type="submit" value="DELETE"></a><?
}
```

Otherwise, `$_SESSION['user']['rank'] == "a"` and `"p"` are treated as two separate expressions.  `"p"` evaluates to true, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['user']['username']) && isset($_SESSION['rank']) && ($_SESSION['rank'] == "a" || $_SESSION['rank'] == "p"))) {?>
     <a href="deletepost.php?id=<? echo $id ?>"><input type="submit" value="DELETE"></a><?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['username']) AND $_SESSION['user']['rank'] == "a" or "p")
```

the p at the end will always give true, so you must enclose your statement, like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['username']) && (($_SESSION['user']['rank'] == "a") || ($_SESSION['user']['rank'] == "p"))
```